# Bootstrap 4 scss files

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to install Bootstrap 4 with Yarn within a Symfony 4 project.

On the [Bootstrap page](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) it states in the ["Whats included" section](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap#whats-included) which files will come, and those are only `.css` files.

When I add the library with yarn, there are no `.scss` files in the directory.

How can I get the SCSS version of Bootstrap 4?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install the bootstrap packet `yarn add bootstrap`. 
The folder named bootstrap will appear in the folder `/node_modules/` which will contain `scss` folder. For work with scss sources, you need a scss to css [compiler](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader) and a [bundler](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/webpack/)

[image]

Comment: First I installed https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass, but it installs bootstrap 3. They say "For Bootstrap 4 use the Bootstrap Ruby gem if you use Ruby, and the main repo otherwise." But the main repo is not providing the sass files and the other one is for Ruby on Rails. So i'm confused :P

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can do this with Yarn, because developers usually want pre-compiled libraries (`dist/`). I am not sure if there is an option.

---

1. Go to the official Boostrap ["Download" page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/).
2. Look for the ["Source files" section](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/).
3. Click: [**<kbd>Download source</kbd>**](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v4.0.0.zip)
4. Inside the zipped-archive, you will find the `scss/` directory.
5. Include that in your application path.